# How to make labels clearer in factoextra::fviz_cluster plot

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, factoextra

I've plotted this cluster plot

```
factoextra::fviz_cluster(clustsub.k2,clustsub, pointsize = 1.2 ,labelsize = 12)
clustsub.k2
```

And this is the result:
[image]

How do I make the labels clearer? I can't read any of the numbers.

Comment: Please provide some example data of clustsub.k2 and clustsub using `dput`

Comment: it's the mushroom classification dataset. and clustsub.k2 is just k means with 2 clusters.

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/uciml/mushroom-classification?select=mushrooms.csv does not show a numeric column which might be used as point labels in the plot. Use `dplyr::distinct(label_column, .keep_all = TRUE)` to ensure to only have one mushroom per label so they won't get overwritten

Comment: @danlooo this works but it reduces my dataset drastically, is there no other way

Comment: It reduces it because your dataset probably consists of mostly duplicates.